# How to create Alist from List using syntax-rules in Scheme?

Tags: macros, scheme, hygiene, syntax-rules

Just as exercise I want to transform:

```lisp
(alist "foo" 1 "bar" 2 "baz" 3)
```

into

```
(("foo" . 1) ("bar" . 2) ("baz" . 3))
```

is this possible with syntax-rules?

My attempt:

```lisp
(define-syntax alist
  (syntax-rules ()
     ((_ a b) (cons a b))
     ((_ x y ...)
      (list (alist x y) ...))))
```

the problem that it expand into:

```
(("foo" . 2) ("foo" . "bar") ("foo" . 4) ("foo" . "baz") ("foo" . 6))
```

is macro alist possible with syntax-rules? How it should look like?

EDIT:

Another attempt

```lisp
(define-syntax alist
  (syntax-rules ()
     ((_ a b) (cons a b))
     ((_ x y z ...)
      (list (alist x y) (alist z ...)))))
```

it returns `(("foo" . 2) (("bar" . 4) ("baz" . 6)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's literals only (like `"foo"` and `2`) you can just do this:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))

(define-syntax alist
  (syntax-rules (alist-builder)
    ((_ alist-builder () (results ...)) 
     '(results ...))
    ((_ alist-builder (a) . rest) 
     (raise 'bad-alist))
    ((_ alist-builder (a b rest ...) (results ...))
     (alist alist-builder (rest ...) (results ... (a . b))))
    ((_ a ...) (alist alist-builder (a ...) ()))))

(alist)         ; ==> ()
(alist "a" 2)   ; ==> (("a" . 2))
(alist a 3 b 4) ; ==> ((a . 3) (b . 4))
(alist a)       ; ==> uncaught exception: bad-alist
```

Of course you are not allowed to mutate this because `(alist a b c d)` is the same as literally writing `'((a . b) (c . d))` which you are not allowed to mutate.

Also if you ever make an alist with `alist-builder` as the first key the internals will leak. You can fix this by splitting up the internal definition and you can hide it from exposure by having both in a library and only export `alist`

Comment: Can you tell me why this is better than my code, that is way simpler? Does it because it have error handling? In my code I can just use 'a and 'x in cons and it will also work with `(alist a 3 b 4)`.

Comment: @jcubic They work different. Your version creates the code that evaluates to an alist. Mine creates the constant literal in compile time. If you use this in a procedure you will recreate the same list again and again with your version and it will be constant literal and made once with mine. Also `(alist)` in your version turns into invalid Scheme code `()`. It should signal an error.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, this is something new for me, because the way I test this and try to understand how it works, is with my implementation of syntax-rules, that evaluate at runtime. I need to rewrite it and add expansion time to my lisp.

Answer (score 2):

I've figure that out:

```lisp
(define-syntax alist
  (syntax-rules ()
     ((_) ())
     ((_ x y z ...)
      (apply list (cons x y) (alist z ...)))))
```

and simplified version:

```lisp
(define-syntax alist
  (syntax-rules ()
     ((_) ())
     ((_ x y z ...)
      (cons (cons x y) (alist z ...)))))
```

Comment: Note that you could use `cons` instead of `apply list`: `cons` is simpler